# Highcharts value series to label

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm going crazy... someone help me?

I've two series of data:

var = (time, value, value2)

The value2 is a difference between the actual value compare to before value, that get to MYSQL Database.

I want two series, one is a value and other is an EMA, and I have it.
I want that this series has a label with the values, and I have it.
I want that the first series has a label with the difference with the second series and I have it.
But, I want that the first and second series has an other label with the info of the value2, and I can't to do it, because I confuse with this code "this.series.userOptions.data[this.point.index][1];"

```
    $dadesborsa[] = "[$databorsa, $valorborsa, $diferencia]";
    $dadesema[] = "[$databorsa, $matriuema[0], $diferencia]";

?>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
Highstock.stockChart('grafica_borsa', {
 title : {
            text : 'Evolució de les accions de <?php echo $matriuaseguradora[2]?>'
                    },
            xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Dates'
                            }
                },
            tooltip: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: '18px'
                    },
                 pointFormatter: function() {
        var series = this.series.chart.series,
          percentage = Highcharts.numberFormat(
            this.y / series[1].points[this.index].y * 100, 2
          );

        return '<span style="color:' +
          this.color + '">●</span> ' +
          this.series.name + ': <b>' +
          Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) +
          '</b> Percentage: ' + percentage + '%<br/>' + 
        this.series.userOptions.data[this.point.index][1];
      },
                    },
series : [{
            name : '<?php echo $matriuaseguradora[2]?>',                       
            data :  [<?php echo join($dadesborsa, ',') ?>],
            id: 'dataseries',
    },{
         name: 'EMA',
        data: [<?php echo join($dadesema, ',') ?>],
        id: 'dataema',
    }
        ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` in a `pointFormatter` function is already a point, so use `this.index` instead of `this.point.index`.

```
  tooltip: {
    style: {
      fontSize: '18px'
    },
    pointFormatter: function() {
      var series = this.series.chart.series,
        percentage = Highcharts.numberFormat(
          this.y / series[1].points[this.index].y * 100, 2
        );

      return '<span style="color:' +
        this.color + '">●</span> ' +
        this.series.name + ': <b>' +
        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) +
        '</b> Percentage: ' + percentage + '%<br/>' +
        this.series.userOptions.data[this.index][1];
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b19gxt4q/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.pointFormatter